# Getting a " ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0" error

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am getting this error:
num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0

This is my code:

```
#DataLoader for train and test data
image_transforms = [
   transforms.Resize((INP_IMAGE_SIZE, INP_IMAGE_SIZE), Image.BICUBIC),
   transforms.ToTensor(),
   transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)),
]

dataloader = DataLoader(
   InpaintDatasetLoader("input_dataset/%s" % DATASET_NAME,
   image_transforms=image_transforms, is_Trainable=True),
   batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
   shuffle=True,
   num_workers=4,
)
print('Length of dataloader is : ',len(dataloader))

test_dataloader = DataLoader(
   InpaintDatasetLoader("input_dataset/%s" % DATASET_NAME,
   image_transforms=image_transforms, is_Trainable=False),
   batch_size=12,
   shuffle=True,
   num_workers=1,
)
print('Length of test dataloader is : ',len(test_dataloader))
```

I m using the CIFR10 dataset.
The link to my colab notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15JqObrQcw9nzveRaWxqa7S8gw4iiWySX?usp=sharing

The entire error screenshot:

[image]

I cant understand what the problem is . I have seen similar questions but none of them provide proper solution to my problem.

Comment: I havent't used this module but looks like you need to pass num_samples >0 while creating object

Comment: What is InpaintDatasetLoader, can't it handle the other parameters? Never seen a DataLoader loading another dataloader.

Comment: @Hackaholic where should I add 'num_samples >0' part ?